# Convert string to nested structures like list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string like

```
str_sample = "[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b', [None, (1, 3)], {'c': 'd'}]]"
```

I am currently using:

```
exec("str2list_sample = "+ str_sample)
```

Is there any much more cleaner approach of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly don't name your variable `str` as it shadows the built-in.

To solve your problem you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
>>> a = "[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b']]"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b']]
```

To address your latest edit

```
>>> str_sample = "[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b', [None, (1, 3)], {'c': 'd'}]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(str_sample)
[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b', [None, (1, 3)], {'c': 'd'}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), but this is not a [good practice](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

```
eval("[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b']]")
[[1, 2], [2.0, 0.3], ['a', 'b']]
```

Comment: I need to load millions of lists.  Why it is not a good practice?

Comment: using eval is, the answer Bhargav gave is pretty good, `literal_eval` raises an exception if it is not a valid datatype, but `eval` will evaluate all python expressions, so you need to be sure that the input you are giving to eval is not something hazardous.

Comment: @NamitSingal In all your future answers do add a link to [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) beautiful explanation as to why `eval` is bad.

Comment: probably should do right now. @BhargavRao also thanks for the answer, got to know literal_eval today ^^